# JPA CriteriaBuilder generics error: CriteriaQuery<capture#2-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Expression<Long>)

Tags: java, generics, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to JPA `CriteriaBuilder` and am running into a generics error with JPA Criteria Queries that I cannot seem to understand or work my way around.  I'm trying to translate the following query into a Criteria query to use in a Spring Data repository:

```
select * from User where id = ( select max(id) from User);
```

I've tried to do the following based on code I've seen at https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Criteria, but it is giving a compile time error:

```
new Specification<User>() {

            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<User> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                root = query.from(User.class);
                cb.greatest(root.<Long>get("id"))
                query.select(cb.max(root.<Long>get("id")));
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        });
```

Of course, I'm just realizing that once I figure out how to specify the query, I'm not even sure how to convert that into a Predicate either.

Am I completely off-base here?  How do I convert the above SQL to a Predicate that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dirty Workaround for the moment:

```
public static User getGreatestId(EntityManager em){
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> userRoot = cq.from(User.class);  
    Path<Long> pathToId = userRoot.get("id");
    cq.select(userRoot).orderBy(cb.desc(pathToId));
    TypedQuery<User> typed = em.createQuery(cq);
    typed.setMaxResults(1);
    return typed.getSingleResult();
}
```

With Subquery:

```
 public static User getGreatestId(EntityManager em){
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);       
    Root<User> userRoot = cq.from(User.class);  
    Path<Long> pathToId = userRoot.get("id");       
    Subquery<Long> subquery = cq.subquery(Long.class);
    Root<User> subRoot = subquery.from(User.class);
    Path<Long> subPathToId = subRoot.get("id");             
    subquery.select(cb.max(subPathToId));       
    cq.select(userRoot).where(cb.equal(pathToId, subquery));
    TypedQuery<User> typed = em.createQuery(cq);       
    return typed.getSingleResult();
}
```

Comment: I tried something very similar (`Predicate p = cb.equal(root.get("id"), cb.greatest(root.<Long>get("id")))`), but am getting errors: Invalid use of aggregate function "MAX(USER1_.ID)"

Comment: i edit an workaround, this give you the user with the highest id back. But i think, thats not the best solution and not equivalent to the given query. But it works ;)

Comment: Thanks.  I had hacked the same thing too. :)  But was hoping there was a neater way to get the same thing using cb.max() or cb.greatest()

Comment: I have build another solution with max() and a subquery. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Ah - perfect!  Thanks so much.  I was missing that piece of how to create the subquery, but this helps out perfectly.